# Mainframe data conversion to electronic PDF - alternative to Emtex?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, mainframe

We are currently converting mainframe data files to PDF using Emtex but it is extremely slow (taking a weekend to convert 50,000).

These need to happen in an automated, secure, FAST manner with very large volume. We don't need to print them, just transfer the electronic PDFs to the client.

I'm researching alternatives to Emtex and have found CICS2PDF, RPM Remote Print Manager and the PDFlib suite that may have potential.

Does anyone have experience with any other tools that I am missing? I would love any additional information.

Comment: What kind of input data do you need to convert to PDF?

Comment: Is your only requirement the speed?
To create a PDF document and send it through email there are probably better choices outside the mainframe considering the cost, the release of CPU load on the mainframe and probably faster.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [afp2pdf](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=iis-transforms).  You end up with "printers" on the mainframe that are defined as scripts that call the afp2pdf utility.  Dump the resulting PDFs into a Unix System Services directory on the mainframe, then fire up your mainframe [FTP](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=ftp-using) or [SFTP](http://dovetail.com/products/ftpsshproxy.html) client and PUT them to your destination(s).

Comment: Thanks, everyone! It looks like we might be forced to stick with our current in-house solution, but I will definitely look into afp2pdf.  Thanks again!